# Double set to -1 from function does not equal to -1 in comparison

Tags: c++

I use the function trace() to calculate the trace of a matrix. This is not important. But for this specific matrix this value is -1. My variable "trace" is set to this from the function. However when I compare this value as a boolean it shows they are not equal. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
double trace = R.trace();
double t = -1;
std::cout << "\nTrace: \n" << trace << "\n Matrix: \n" << R;
printf("\nbool: %d: sub: %f type: %s\n", trace == -1.0, trace, typeid(trace).name());
printf("\nbool: %d: sub: %f type: %s\n", t == -1.0, t, typeid(t).name());
```

Output:

```
Trace: 
-1
 Matrix: 
           1  3.52206e-06 -2.42913e-11
 3.52206e-06           -1  6.44708e-06
-1.58434e-12 -6.44708e-06           -1
bool: 0: sub: -1.000000 type: d

bool: 1: sub: -1.000000 type: d
```

So for some reason it does not realize they are equal?

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0 x86_64

Answer (score 1):

> for this specific matrix this value is -1.

Ahhh, but it isn't!

It **displays** as negative one.

Low order bits of the significand are being suppressed from the display.
Add +1 to it and print that sum if you want to see them.

Alternatively, use `%a` sprintf formatting to see the hex representation.
It reveals all bits.

---

Given a pair of
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)
numbers `a`, `b`, it is generally frowned on to ask whether `a == b`.

You're usually better off defining a tiny epsilon
and then asking if `abs(a - b) < eps`.

In this code, rather than passing this expression to printf():
`trace == -1.0`,
prefer to pass `abs(trace - (-1))` (so you're adding +1).
Then you can compare that quantity to a small epsilon.

Comment: Wow, I thought printing the %f would of been enough to show the lower order bits but I guess not. Ok thanks.

Comment: This is code review, not stack overflow.